# Removing an echo from a class method - PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to remove an echo from a class method from outside the class. I've managed to do it using this coding:

```
function rewrite() {
    $rewrite = new ReflectionMethod( 'WPLogin', 'head' );

    $filename = $rewrite->getFileName();
    $start_line = $rewrite->getStartLine();
    $end_line = $rewrite->getEndLine()-1;

    $length = $end_line - $start_line;
    $source = file($filename);
    $body = implode('', array_slice($source, $start_line, $length));
    $body = preg_replace( '/echo \'\<\!(.*?)\n/', '', $body);

    eval($body);
}
```

It works, but it's not "safe to use", as it can be tricky and it is using `eval` which is something to avoid.

Is there a better way to do this, or atleast a safer way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap the method call in an [output buffer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php):

```
ob_start();

// Call method here.

ob_end_clean();
```

This will remove any output done by the function e.g. `echo`, `print_r`, `var_dump`

Comment: I'm kinda confused on how to implement this, because I'm not calling the method, the method is basically already initiated in the core itself.

Comment: @J.Doe Can you elaborate on how the method/class is called and what the core is? I don't understand what you mean: _"the method is basically already initiated in the core itself"_.

Comment: I'm using this code in WordPress, and the class method is from a different plugin. In that method there's some advertisement I want to remove. So I gotta remove it from outside the class while the method is already loaded.

Comment: @J.Doe That's a bit tricker :) If your code isn't calling the method then it's a lot harder to control the output. In your case I think your original code is the best solution that I can think of.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Is there any other way using this code to avoid `eval`? After all those stories I'm kinda scared to use it.

Comment: @J.Doe No I don't think there is a better way to do it. If you did have control over how the method was called then it would be a different story :)